# send vs return effects

Tags: mixing, effects, cubase

I was reading an article about reverb effects, and it said in that article that if you want to have good reverb effect, you can EQ the send  and sometimes EQ the return sound.

Now, I only know a single method to do that. I just put an EQ as an insert, after my reverb plugin(in FX channel). Am I EQing the send or return? And how could I use the other method?

By the way, my DAW is Cubase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Cubase-specific [anything since about v5 can do it this way]

To EQ the send [separately from the actual channel] you would send the channel to a new channel instead of Stereo Bus, & add EQ to your new channel, but don't assign it to an output, instead remove it from Stereo Bus - so in effect it just 'vanishes'.
You use a regular FX send from that to your reverb.
You can use this for example to make only S's spin into a long bright reverb, without all the mud sending to it as well [George Michael trick from late 80's, early 90's]

To EQ the return, you EQ the reverb return itself on your FX channel, as your original example.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. i just did what you said, but there is a problem . you said : dont assign it to an output, instead remove it from stereo bus... when i did that , the reverb effect was also gone. no reverb sound at all. what did i do wrong? and what do you mean by making S spin? thanks again for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Reverb usually is a "linear" effect as is EQ.  That means short of exceeding valid input levels, it doesn't matter whether you put EQ or reverb first.  If you are using analog devices, either of those effects would provide a more level input to the other, so you'd put the device with worse signal-to-noise ratio last.  Digitally, there should not be much of a difference.